# Blender and dental addon

Tags: python, add-on

I am a beginner in using blender .
I read about the dental cadcam add-on , and i searched for the script and could not find it .

Where can I get this addon?

Comment: was it this? https://sites.google.com/site/blenderdental/ it was feature also on BN a couple of _years_ago http://www.blendernation.com/2012/01/27/open-dental-cad/.. I guess it could be not much up to date with recent blender versions...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about downloading an unofficial addon.

Comment: @someonewithpc I guess pretty much all of non-bundled blender addons are "unofficial". I don't see a reason why this site could not answer where to get some addon. Yes a simple google query solves it but there are far worst (aka I am lazy to search) questions on this site.

Comment: The answer to this question is going to be a link, which is generally discouraged.

Comment: @someonewithpc True, that I have admit is a good argument. Would be probably best to share the code here if someone has it. It looks like the addon is abandoned and the source is lost.

Comment: Yeah, that would be a good solution.

Comment: @patmo141 might know alternatives

Comment: Thank you all for your kind answers , highly appreciated , but situation still same , i only read about this dental addon , but concretely i cannot get it !
someonewithpic good idea , i hope that some one who has the code WILL SHARE IT HERE ! COME ON GUYS IT'S CHRISTMAS TIME :)

Comment: ..any script version will be ook (older , newer , whatever ! )...thks

Comment: You can talk a look at github.com/patmo141/odc_public/wiki. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

I am the author the addon.  I will update the google site to point to the github repository.  The addon has not been "abandoned" but it is certainly not actively maintained or developed heavily.

https://github.com/patmo141/odc_public

Thanks,
Patrick

Comment: I was trying to locate the ODC add-in but could not find the internet nor the link you provided https://github.com/patmo141/odc_public helped me with that. Is that add-in still available and compatible with recent version of Blender? Would appreciate your help on this. Thank you, smaciu

Comment: Read the wiki at the link above.